# Are there any downsides if someone picks up my boarding pass and adds my reservation to their Business Extra account for small business program credit

Tags: air-travel, tickets, loyalty-programs, privacy

I read on [viewfromthewing.com](https://viewfromthewing.com/american-has-started-redacting-frequent-flyer-numbers-on-boarding-passes/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://viewfromthewing.com/american-has-started-redacting-frequent-flyer-numbers-on-boarding-passes/)):

> To be sure, your boarding pass still has a bar code. Someone with a bar code scanner or app could read it. But that’s not the person most likely to pick up your boarding pass. It actually seems more likely that someone would pick up your boarding pass and add your reservation to their Business ExtrAA account [sic] for small business program credit (in addition to you receiving your miles).

Are there any downsides for me if someone picks up my boarding pass and adds my reservation to their [Business ExtrA account](https://www.businessextra.com/program/how-it-works.htm) for small business program credit?

Comment: why are downsides for **you** of that particular action a requirement for the airline to stop printing the number on the pass? There are clear and obvious downsides for **the airline** if someone adds random flights to their account for extra points. And the article lists possible downsides for **you** (unrelated to a business extra account) of having it on the pass.

Comment: I’m a bit puzzled… I’m not familiar with that program, but it would be logical that either they add the specific flight, and then the FF number is irrelevant, probably the only relevant bits are booking ref and/or ticket number and/or name, in which case masking the FF number is useless (for that) or they can just add the FF account itself rather than just individual flights, and I would expect a bit of a confirmation process. This looks like a big shortcut.